# Создание графиков на vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, график, графики

никак не могу найти нужную библиотеку с нужным функционалом для создания графика (пример на рисунке).
Может кто-то сможет подсказать библиотеку для vue.js?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Требуется изобразить изменения кластеров за указанный промежуток времени.

По оси Х дата/время (можно менять масштаб по оси).

По оси Y изменение значения кластеров, которые произошли за какой-то промежуток времени.

Пример:
Для оранжевого кластера изменения происходили:
По оси Y с 30 - 40 (пускай будет минут).
По оси X с 2 - 4 элементов.
Желательно с возможностью задания гибкой цветовой палитры для кластеров (градиент/прозрачность).

P.S. Рисую я так себе)

Comment: Для графического отображения данных я бы посоветовал библиотеку d3.js https://vuejsexamples.com/tag/d3/

Comment: Да, это хороший вариант, но я хотел найти более простое решение))